# Wordpress stylesheets and other files not linking up

Tags: php, css, database, wordpress, export

I've uploaded a clients wordpress site to a test domain: 101share.co.uk . I had everything working on localhost and changed the urls and stuff before uploading, from http:// localhost/wincheapguesthouse/ to http://101share.co.uk .

After uploading and importing the database the result I get seems to be that many files are not being found, but they are there. In the source code if I look for , it can't find it. But if I look for  or "http://101share.co.uk/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-16aad54/assets/css/app.css"
Then I'm able to find it.

Have I got something wrong with the data base or is there a url I need to change, I can't change each link because I don't know exactly how much it is effecting.

I stressing out a little over this because it's a clients site and I need to get things working for them to see. So any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How did you migrate the files? Did you go through the WordPress migration plan? Have you also amended the database configuration, and moved the database over?

Comment: When you get your stylesheets and such, are you using `get_template_directory_uri` or some other function?

Comment: Also, what is showing up in the webserver error logs? I was getting internal server errors when I clicked on links, so there should be something showing there.

Comment: its seems like the base url was not available

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, on your page your CSS etc seems to start "/plugins..." for instance although should be "/wp-content/plugins..."?

Although, the ones starting "/assets" don't seem to exist no matter what I try.

I suggest looking over your folder structure and adjusting your links accordingly in (most likely) the header.php for that theme.

Comment: All the files are there, if I go to - http://101share.co.uk/wp-content/themes/retlehs-roots-16aad54/assets/css/app.css - Then I find the file. but I'm not sure why it isn't looking there for the links files automatically. is there somewhere in the php or database I can change it so that it adds the necessary wp-content and the theme folders etc?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It's that the roots theme tries to rewrite your urls in a way that Apache doesn't agree with.

If you comment out these lines under "config.php" it will work.

```
add_theme_support('root-relative-urls');    // Enable relative URLs
add_theme_support('rewrites');              // Enable URL rewrites
```